# XML::Twig xpath bar

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

I'm using XML::Twig to process this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<termEntry>
    <langSet lang="en">
        <ntig>
            <termGrp>
                <term>trail</term>
                <termNote type="partOfSpeech">noun</termNote>
            </termGrp>
            <descrip type="context">Like in a forest</descrip>
        </ntig>
    </langSet>
</termEntry>
```

I'm using the following code to process it:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig_handlers = {
    termEntry => sub { for my $node($_[1]->findnodes('.//descrip|.//termNote')){print $node->text;}},
};

my $twig= new XML::Twig(
                                TwigRoots           => { termEntry => 1},
                                TwigHandlers        => $twig_handlers,
);

$twig->parsefile('C:\Users\me\file.xml');
```

The code fails with:

```
error in xpath expression .//descrip|.//termNote around descrip|.//termNote at 
C:\Users\nate\Desktop\test.pl line 6
```

I've been trying different things, and any time I use the '|' character in the xpath it breaks the program. It works just fine at http://www.xpathtester.com (thought I replace '.' with '//'). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it™:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub process {
  my ( $twig, $elt ) = @_;
  print $_->text, "\n" for ( $elt->findnodes( './/descrip' ),
                             $elt->findnodes( './/termNote' ) );
}

my $xml = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { termEntry => \&process } );

$xml->parse( <<XML );
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<termEntry>
    <langSet lang="en">
        <ntig>
            <termGrp>
                <term>trail</term>
                <termNote type="partOfSpeech">noun</termNote>
            </termGrp>
            <descrip type="context">Like in a forest</descrip>
        </ntig>
    </langSet>
</termEntry>
XML
```

#### Output

```
Like a forest
noun
```

Comment: Hehe, not sure why I didn't think of that. I'll use it if noone can figure out the XPath.

Comment: @NateGlenn You should use it because the XPath you use is correct. The module simply doesn't support it. Also +1 for the "there's more than one way to do it:) - I can't upvote more for today. Have to wait 48 mins:)

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.39/Twig.pm) :

"XPath expressions are limited to using the child and descendant axis (indeed you can't specify an axis), and predicates cannot be nested. You can use the string, or string() function (except in twig_roots triggers)"

Your XPath is correct. You might wanna try : XML::Twig::Xpath then you get the full Xpath power :)

Comment: That is very useful information, thank you. Sorry, but when I read your answer I realized I'd misentered the question. I was using './', not '//', to select the nodes. Testing at the validator site required me to use '//'.

Comment: @NateGlenn You realize that '/' is very different than '//' right?

Comment: @NateGlenn : `'./'` won't work, I think `'.//'` is what you mean